# the program does not end and nothing happens

Tags: c

Write a program, divided into functions with parameters, which will load a dynamic array of integers until the user enters the number 0. Initially, assume that the array will contain only 5 such numbers. If the user tries to enter more numbers than the table can store, the program should detect this situation and increase its size by another 5 elements. The program should repeat the steps described in the previous sentence whenever the table ends in the table and until the user has finished entering numbers. After all, the program should write the contents of the table on the screen and free the allocated memory.

```
     void fill_array(int *);
void print_array(int *, int);
void *add_memory(int);
int main()
{
    int x;
    int *array_pointer = (int*)calloc(5,sizeof(int));
    if(array_pointer)
    {
        fill_array(array_pointer);
        x = sizeof(array_pointer)/sizeof(array_pointer[0]);
        print_array(array_pointer, x);
    }

    return 0;
}

void fill_array(int *array)
{
    int i = 0, k = 5;
    printf("Please fill an array with at least 5 digits: ");

    while(scanf("%d", &array[i]) != 0)
    {
        if(i > 5)
        {
            k++;
            array = (int*)add_memory(k);

        }
        i++;
    }
}

void *add_memory(int a)
{

    void *array_ptr = realloc(array_ptr,a*sizeof(int));
    return array_ptr;
}

void print_array(int *array, int b)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i< b;i++)
        printf("%d ",array[i]);
    puts("");
}
```

Comment: Where is `add_memory` definition? In any case, if it is using `realloc` or something it is not going to work as it will modify the `array` value, which will not get reflected outside `fill_array`.

Comment: Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `void *add_memory(int a)` leaks memory and will lose all your existing data if `realloc` fails returning `NULL`.

Comment: Note that `while(scanf("%d", &array[i]) != 0)` should be `while(scanf("%d", &array[i]) == 1)` because `EOF` won't be detected.

Comment: There are so many problems in your code. For example, look at the `add_memory` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the functional version of your code. You have to enter `0` to stop the program and print the information obtained. Though it's not fully complete. You have to do to following things.

1. Error checking
2. Cosmetic changes i.e. writing comments etc.
3. Deallocate the resources

Though it seems no more deallocation is required.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fill_array(int *);
void print_array(int *, int);

int *add_memory(int **, int);
int k = 5;

int main()
{
    int x;
    int *array_pointer = (int*) calloc(k,sizeof(int));

    if(array_pointer)
    {
        fill_array(array_pointer);
        print_array(array_pointer, k);
    }

    if(array_pointer)
    {
    /* Deallocate the memory. */
    free(array_pointer);
    }

    return 0;
}

void fill_array(int *array)
{
    int i = 0;
    int number;
    printf("Please fill an array with at least 5 digits:");
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\r\nEnter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &number);

        if (number == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (i >= 4)
            {
                k++;
                array = (int*) add_memory(&array, k);

                if (!array)
                {
                    break;
                }

                array[i] = number;
            }
            else
            {
                array[i] = number;
            }

            i++;
        }

    }
}

int *add_memory(int **array_ptr, int a)
{
    printf("Allocating more memory\r\n");

    *array_ptr = realloc(*array_ptr, a*sizeof(int));

    if (!*array_ptr)
    {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory.\r\n");
    }

    return *array_ptr;
}

void print_array(int *array, int b)
{
    int i;
    printf("\r\nPrinting array\r\n");

    for(i=0;i< b;i++)
        printf("%d ",array[i]);
    puts("");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This function doesn't make sense:

```
void *add_memory(int a)
{

  void *array_ptr = realloc(array_ptr, a * sizeof(int));
  return array_ptr;
}
```

You may call `realloc` only upon a pointer that has been previously allocated by `malloc`, `calloc`, or another `realloc` or upon a `NULL` pointer. In your code `array_ptr` hasn't been initialized, and calling `realloc` with an uninitialized pointer will not end well.

But the overall structure of your program is very poor and there are certainly other issues than the one in the answers.

Comment: @WeatherVane there is no `array_ptr` in `main`, only `array_pointer`, but yeah, it's easy to get lost in this mess.

Comment: Same diagnosis though. The pointer here is unrelated to the one in `main`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem code is `while(scanf("%d", &array[i]) != 0)`

Let's see return value of `scanf`

```
NAME
       scanf,  fscanf, sscanf, vscanf, vsscanf, vfscanf 

       ...

RETURN VALUE
       These functions return the number of input items  successfully  matched
       and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the
       event of an early matching failure.

       The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before  either
       the  first  successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.  EOF is
       also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator
       for  the  stream  (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the
       error.
```

So in your case, `scanf()` always return `1` when you input integer continuously.

BTW, there are other problems in your code.

1. `x = sizeof(array_pointer)/sizeof(array_pointer[0])`

   `array_pointer` is a pointer, so `sizeof(array_pointer)` will return a pointer size(32 or 64 or other bits) instead of a array size.
2. `array = (int*)add_memory(k)`

   this code will realloc memory, so when `fill_array` function is done. `array_pointer` may pointer to an address that has been freed.
3. `void *array_ptr = realloc(array_ptr, a * sizeof(int))`

   `array_ptr` is a non-initialized variable.

Comment: and how can I fix my program ?

Comment: @Aimin check the value of array[i]: `while(scanf("%d", &array[i]) != EOF && array[i] != 0)`

Comment: @Aimin it's hard to fix your program. It basically needs to be rewritten from scratch.

Comment: There's no easy fix for this code. It appears to include a number of fundamental misunderstandings about how C and the C standard library work. You should try and approach this *one problem at a time* instead of piling on so much at once. Go with a test-driven development approach to be sure each piece works correctly before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

This is working code for `fill_array`.:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMBERTHRESHOLD 5

int *fill_array(int *nbvalues)
{
  int *array_ptr = NULL;  // hint: read up the specs of realloc
  int actualsize = 0;    // actual size of dynamic array
  int index = 0;         // index of next number to be stored in array

  // initially the array is "full", it contains zero numbers
  // and there is there is space left for zero numbers

  while (1)          // loop forever
  {
    int v;
    scanf("%d", &v);

    if (v == 0)
      break;           // user entered 0 => we stop the loop

    if (actualsize == index)
    {
      // the array is full, we need to allocate space for NUMBERTHRESHOLD more numbers
      actualsize += NUMBERTHRESHOLD;
      array_ptr = realloc(array_ptr, actualsize * sizeof(int));   // reallocate memory
    }

    array_ptr[index++] = v; // store number entered by user
  }

  *nbvalues = index - 1;   // index - 1 is the actual number of numbers in array
  return array_ptr;        // return the pointer to first element of array
}

int main(void)
{
  int nbvalues;
  int *array_ptr = fill_array(&nbvalues);
}
```

Things that need to be done:

- you need to write the `print_array` function and call it
- you need to free the memory
- there is absolutely no error checking done (which is fine for a first shot)